# Looking for the correct SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have those 2 tables:

```
table "libs"
|lib_id|name |
|1    |lib01|
|2    |lib02|
|3    |lib03|
|4    |lib04|
|5    |lib05|

table "req_libs"
|lib_id|req_lib_id|
|2     |3         |
|2     |4         |
|4     |3         |
|5     |3         |
|5     |1         |
```

What SQL queries should I issue to get the following results?

1. Get the names of all libs that are required by lib02. Expected result: lib03,lib04
2. Get the names of all libs that use lib03. Expected result: lib02,lib04,lib05

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Have you tried something yet?

Comment: sounds like homework. show your attempts so far, so maybe someone will help you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a free code writing service. Write the SQL queries *yourself* and if you encounter a problem with that, post those SQL queries with a clear explanation of what you expect and what you get instead. 
Please check out [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Hi all and thanks for your comments. I was expecting the _negative_ comments. At age 72 and with 45 years as a teacher I should have known better. Many thanks to @dadde who went to great lengths not only with providing the response I was looking for but also trying to educate me by providing a link to SqlFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Get the names of all libs that are required by lib02. Expected
    result: lib03,lib04**

```
SELECT t3.name
FROM libs t1
INNER JOIN req_libs t2 ON t1.lib_id = t2.lib_id
INNER JOIN libs t3 ON t2.req_lib_id = t3.lib_id
WHERE t1.name = 'lib02';
```

**2. Get the names of all libs that use lib03. Expected result:
    lib02,lib04,lib05**

```
SELECT libs.name 
FROM libs
WHERE libs.lib_id IN (
SELECT req_libs.lib_id
FROM libs, req_libs
  WHERE libs.name = 'lib03'
  AND libs.lib_id = req_libs.req_lib_id
);
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2731df/18

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOINs in this fashion:

```
select t3.*
from libs t1
inner join req_libs t2 on t1.lib_id = t2.lib_id
inner join libs t3 on t2.req_lib_id = t3.lib_id
where t1.name = 'lib01';
```